# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Use HttpContext in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this httpcontext claim that I would like to use in my view to show the current users username. This is how I do it so far:

```
<p>@Context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Type == "UserName")</p>
```

However, the result is something like this:

> UserName: user@email.com

Am I missing something? I tried to do this:

```
@Context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()
```

But it doesn't allow me to use Select after the SingleOrDefault.

Comment: Is it should be `@Context.User.Claims.Where(u => u.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns single element that matches with the criteria, not another `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` collection which can be `Select`-ed later.

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value
>   if that element is not found.

You should use [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) to return a collection before using [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
@Context.User.Claims.Where(u => u.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()
```

For C# 6.0 and above, use null-conditional operator to get its value:

```
@Context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Type == "UserName")?.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, the result is something like this:

Because `.SingleOrDefault` returns a claim item, then the view renders the item with its `.ToString` method.

> But it doesn't allow me to use Select after the SingleOrDefault.

`.SingleOrDefault` returns a item in the collection, while `.Select` expects a collection. You should just visit the `.Value` property of this item directly.

```
@Context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Type == "UserName")?.Value
```